# Keeping a button(div) in center

Tags: html, css, button

im new at html and still learning.
Im trying to keep a button in center(div) but i dont really know how i should do it. I used the margins to place it around. - And it works well when the window is fullscreened, but when i make the window small, the button changes position.

[Sorry if english isn't perfect xD]

Here's the code of the button(CSS):

```
  .signupbutton {


    position:relative;
    margin-left: 880px;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0d8f64), color-stop(1, #0d8f64));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0d8f64', endColorstr='#0d8f64',GradientType=0);

    background-color:#0d8f64;

    -moz-border-radius:14px;
    -webkit-border-radius:14px;
    border-radius:14px;

    border:2px solid #424745;

    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:12px 42px;
    text-decoration:none;

    text-shadow:0px -1px 0px #5b6178;

}
.signupbutton:hover {

    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0d8f64), color-stop(1, #0d8f64));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0d8f64 5%, #0d8f64 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0d8f64', endColorstr='#0d8f64',GradientType=0);

    background-color:#0d8f64;
}
.signupbutton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will keep an element in the center of its parent:

```
margin: 0px auto; width: 100px;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering so quick! :D Anyways both of the answers work if i have the test window full screen. But when i resize the window smaller, the button changes completely position :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.signupbutton {
    ....
    /*Change display to block*/
    display:block;
    /* Add margin auto*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*Set a fixed width*/
    width: 50px; //or whatever width you need

   ....
}
```

[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RTGfW/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering so quick! :D Anyways both of the answers work if i have the test window full screen. But when i resize the window smaller, the button changes completely position :S

Comment: I've just tested the fiddle again and when i change window size the button remains in the middle.

Comment: You're completely right, it works. I made a brand new html and css file, and only added the elements i needed, and now it works perfectly :) THANKS. Is there a place i should mark this "thread" for answered or something?

Comment: Click the 'v' sign next to the answer